# XOR function failing in special cases

Tags: python, encryption, des

I want to preface this by saying that the issue is python related not DES related.
I made a DES encryption program for my cryptology class. ignoring key functions, the general format of this encryption is: plaintext -> (permutated) -> L0 R0. L(i)=R(i-1). R(i)=L(i-1) XOR F(E(R(i-1) XOR K(i)))
my program is currently made to output each step along this process. at each step, my program works as intended, until i get to the final XOR before the end of that round of encryption. The XOR method i use is used before this issue and works as intended.
Here is the class i made:

```
class DES:
    def printListInX(self, l, x):
        strList=""
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if i % x ==0:
                strList+=" "
            strList+=str(l[i])
        return strList
    def byteArrToInt(self,bits):
        #generally only used for turning 3 bits to 1 num
        temp=8*bits[0] + 4*bits[1] +2*bits[2]+bits[3]
        return temp 
    def intTo4bits(self, n)->list:
        bStr = '' 
        while n > 0: 
            bStr =  str(n % 2) +bStr 
            n = n >> 1 
        while len(bStr)<4:
            bStr="0"+bStr
        return [int(x) for x in bStr]
    def shiftLeft(self, h, num):
        for i in range(num):
            h=h[1:]+[h[0]]
        return h
    def xorBytes(self, n=[], m=[])->list:
        #assume n m of equal size
        temp=[]
        for i in range(len(n)):
            if n[i] == m[i]:
                temp.append(0)
            else:
                temp.append(1)
        return temp
    def get2from1(self, L):
        temp1=[]
        temp2=[]
        half=len(L)/2 #len is assumed even so no need to floor
        for i in range(len(L)):
            if i <half:
                temp1.append(L[i])
            else:
                temp2.append(L[i])
        return temp1, temp2
    def hexToBinList(self,h):
        binDict={
            "0":"0000","1":"0001","2":"0010","3":"0011","4":"0100",
            "5":"0101","6":"0110","7":"0111","8":"1000","9":"1001",
            "A":"1010","a":"1010","b":"1011","B":"1011",
            "C":"1100","c":"1100","D":"1101","d":"1101",
            "E":"1110","e":"1110","F":"1111","f":"1111"
        }
        if isinstance(h, str):
            strList=list(h)
        elif isinstance(h,list):
            #assume its a list of hex values
            strList=h
        ans=[]
        for c in strList:
            ans+=list(binDict[c])
        return ans
    def process(self, h):
        if isinstance(h, str):
            if len(h)==64:
                #make into array of those ints
                #assuming 64 len string is only 1 or 0
                temp=list(h)
                return [int(x) for x in temp]
            elif len(h)==16:
                return self.hexToBinList(h)
        elif isinstance(h, list):
            if len(h)==64:
                #assume binary
                return h
            elif len(h)==16:
                return self.hexToBinList(h)
        #else?    if int do i convert to hex?

    def initialPermutation(self, ptList):
        #reorder bits, newList[0]=ptList[57] (58 but indexing starts at 1 not 0)
        newList=[]
        for i in range(len(ptList)):
            newList.append(ptList[self.ipTable[i] - 1])
        return newList

    def PC1(self,keyList):
        pc1Table=[57,49,41,33,25,17,9,
            1,58,50,42,34,26,18,
            10,2,59,51,43,35,27,
            19,11,3,60,52,44,36,
            
            63,55,47,39,31,23,15,
            7,62,54,46,38,30,22,
            14,6,61,53,45,37,29,
            21,13,5,28,20,12,4]
        #len(keyList)==64
        #len(ans)==56
        ans=[]
        for i in range(56):
            ans.append(keyList[pc1Table[i] - 1])
        return ans

    def PC2(self, keyList):
        pc2Table=[14,17,11,24,1,5,3,28,
            15,6,21,10,23,19,12,4,
            26,8,16,7,27,20,13,2,
            41,52,31,37,47,55,30,40,
            51,45,33,48,44,49,39,56,
            34,53,46,42,50,36,29,32]
        #len(keyList)=56
        #len(ans)=48
        ans=[]
        for i in range(48):
            ans.append(keyList[pc2Table[i] - 1])
        return ans

    def expansion(self, R:list)->list:
        eTable=[32,1,2,3,4,5,
            4,5,6,7,8,9,
            8,9,10,11,12,13,
            12,13,14,15,16,17,
            16,17,18,19,20,21,
            20,21,22,23,24,25,
            24,25,26,27,28,29,
            28,29,30,31,32,1]
        #len(R)=32
        #len(ans)=48
        ans=[]
        for i in range(48):
            ans.append(R[eTable[i] - 1])
        return ans

    def s1box(self, bits)->list:
        #bits is R XOR K. will be broken and sent to each box class internally
        box=[
            [14,4,13,1,2,15,11,8,3,10,6,12,5,9,0,7],
            [0,15,7,4,14,2,13,1,10,6,12,11,9,5,3,8],
            [4,1,14,8,13,6,2,11,15,12,9,7,3,10,5,0],
            [15,12,8,2,4,9,1,7,5,11,3,14,10,0,6,13]
        ]
        usable=bits[:6]
        bits=bits[6:]
        row=int( (str(usable[0]) + str(usable[-1])), 2)
        col=self.byteArrToInt(usable[1:-1])
        print('bits from s1box: ', self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]))
        return self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]) + self.s2box(bits)
      
    def s2box(self, bits)->list:
        box=[
            [15,1,8,14,6,11,3,4,9,7,2,13,12,0,5,10],
            [3,13,4,7,15,2,8,14,12,0,1,10,6,9,11,5],
            [0,14,7,11,10,4,13,1,5,8,12,6,9,3,2,15],
            [13,8,10,1,3,15,4,2,11,6,7,12,0,5,14,9]
        ]
        usable=bits[:6]
        bits=bits[6:]
        row=int( (str(usable[0]) + str(usable[-1])), 2)
        col=self.byteArrToInt(usable[1:-1])
        print('bits from s2box: ', self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]))
        return self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]) + self.s3box(bits) 

    def s3box(self, bits)->list:
        box=[
            [10,0,9,14,6,3,15,5,1,13,12,7,11,4,2,8],
            [13,7,0,9,3,4,6,10,2,8,5,14,12,11,15,1],
            [13,6,4,9,8,15,3,0,11,1,2,12,5,10,14,7],
            [1,10,13,0,6,9,8,7,4,15,14,3,11,5,2,12]
        ]
        usable=bits[:6]
        bits=bits[6:]
        row=int( (str(usable[0]) + str(usable[-1])), 2)
        col=self.byteArrToInt(usable[1:-1])
        print('bits from s3box: ', self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]))
        return self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]) + self.s4box(bits)

    def s4box(self, bits)->list:
        box=[
            [7,13,14,3,0,6,9,10,1,2,8,5,11,12,4,15],
            [13,8,11,5,6,15,0,3,4,7,2,12,1,10,14,9],
            [10,6,9,0,12,11,7,13,15,1,3,14,5,2,8,4],
            [3,15,0,6,10,1,13,8,9,4,5,11,12,7,2,14]
        ]
        usable=bits[:6]
        bits=bits[6:]
        row=int( (str(usable[0]) + str(usable[-1])), 2)
        col=self.byteArrToInt(usable[1:-1])
        print('bits from s4box: ', self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]))
        return self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]) + self.s5box(bits)
    
    def s5box(self, bits)->list:
        box=[
            [2,12,4,1,7,10,11,6,8,5,3,15,13,0,14,9],
            [14,11,2,12,4,7,13,1,5,0,15,10,3,9,8,6],
            [4,2,1,11,10,13,7,8,15,9,12,5,6,3,0,14],
            [11,8,12,7,1,14,2,13,6,15,0,9,10,4,5,3]
        ]
        usable=bits[:6]
        bits=bits[6:]
        row=int( (str(usable[0]) + str(usable[-1])), 2)
        col=self.byteArrToInt(usable[1:-1])
        print('bits from s5box: ', self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]))
        return self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]) + self.s6box(bits)

    def s6box(self, bits)->list:
        box=[
            [12,1,10,15,9,2,6,8,0,13,3,4,14,7,5,11],
            [10,15,4,2,7,12,9,5,6,1,13,14,0,11,3,8],
            [9,14,15,5,2,8,12,3,7,0,4,10,1,13,11,6],
            [4,3,2,12,9,5,15,10,11,14,1,7,6,0,8,13]
        ]
        usable=bits[:6]
        bits=bits[6:]
        row=int( (str(usable[0]) + str(usable[-1])), 2)
        col=self.byteArrToInt(usable[1:-1])
        print('bits from s6box: ', self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]))
        return self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]) + self.s7box(bits)

    def s7box(self, bits)->list:
        box=[
            [4,11,2,14,15,0,8,13,3,12,9,7,5,10,6,1],
            [13,0,11,7,4,9,1,10,14,3,5,12,2,15,8,6],
            [1,4,11,13,12,3,7,14,10,15,6,8,0,5,9,2],
            [6,11,13,8,1,4,10,7,9,5,0,15,14,2,3,12]
        ]
        usable=bits[:6]
        bits=bits[6:]
        row=int( (str(usable[0]) + str(usable[-1])), 2)
        col=self.byteArrToInt(usable[1:-1])
        print('bits from s7box: ', self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]))
        return self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]) + self.s8box(bits)

    def s8box(self, bits)->list:
        box=[
            [13,2,8,4,6,15,11,1,10,9,3,14,5,0,12,7],
            [1,15,13,8,10,3,7,4,12,5,6,11,0,14,9,2],
            [7,11,4,1,9,12,14,2,0,6,10,13,15,3,5,8],
            [2,1,14,7,4,10,8,13,15,12,9,0,3,5,6,11]
        ]
        #bits should not be len 6
        row=int( (str(bits[0]) + str(bits[-1])), 2)
        col=self.byteArrToInt(bits[1:-1])
        print('bits from s8box: ', self.intTo4bits(box[row][col]))
        return self.intTo4bits(box[row][col])

    def pBox(self, bits)->list:
        box=[16,7,20,21,29,12,28,17,
            1,15,23,26,5,18,31,10,
            2,8,24,14,32,27,3,9,
            19,13,30,6,22,11,4,25]
        ans=[]
        for i in range(32):
            ans.append(bits[box[i] - 1])
        print('bits from pBox: ',self.printListInX(ans, 4))
        return ans

    def F(self, R:list, K:list)->list:
        #expand R from 32 to 48 bits
        expR=self.expansion(R)
        print('R after expansion: ', self.printListInX(expR, 6))
        #XOR newR with K
        rXorK=self.xorBytes(expR,K)
        print('R XOR K: ', self.printListInX(rXorK, 6))
        #break into 8 sub lists (size 6 each) for S boxes
        afterSbox=self.s1box(rXorK)    #should now be 32 bits   
        #P box permutation
        ans=self.pBox(afterSbox)
        return ans

    def finalPermutation(self, bits:list)->list:
        newList=[]
        for i in range(len(bits)):
            newList.append(bits[self.ipTableINV[i] - 1])
        return newList

    def encrypt(self, pt, key, numRounds):
        ################# SOMETHIGN WRONG ALGORITHMETICALLY #####################
        ############ i think its because i get L0 and R0 but never actually use them in F
        self.pt=self.process(pt) #will be type list
        self.key = self.process(key)#will be type list
        self.numRounds=numRounds #should always be 16

        #do IP on pt to get L,R
        newPtList=self.initialPermutation(self.pt)
        print('PT after first permutation: ', self.printListInX(newPtList,4))
        L,R=self.get2from1(newPtList)
        print("L0: ", self.printListInX(L, 4), "\tR0: ", self.printListInX(R, 4))
        #do PC1 on key to get C,D
        key56bits=self.PC1(self.key) 
        print('key after PC1: ', self.printListInX(key56bits, 4))
        C,D=self.get2from1(key56bits)
        print('initail C: ', self.printListInX(C, 4), '\ninitial D: ', self.printListInX(D, 4))
        shift1=[0,1,8,15]
        for i in range(numRounds):
            print('\n\nstart of round ', (i+1),'\n\n')
            newL=R
            #newC=C (shifted left x times)
            #newD=D (shifted left x times)
            #x depends on roundnum
            if i in shift1:
                C=self.shiftLeft(C,1)
                D=self.shiftLeft(D,1)
            else:
                C=self.shiftLeft(C,2)
                D=self.shiftLeft(D,2)
            #K=COMPRESS(newC,newD)
            print('after shift C: ', self.printListInX(C, 4), '\nafter shift D: ', self.printListInX(D, 4))
            K=self.PC2(C+D) 
            print('K', (i+1), ': ', self.printListInX(K, 6))
            #newR=L XOR F(R,K)
            fOfRK=self.F(R,K)            
            print('F of R0,K1: ', self.printListInX(fOfRK, 4))
            print('before final XOR')
            print('L',i,': ', self.printListInX(L, 4))
            print('F',(i+1),': ',self.printListInX(fOfRK,4))
            ################### start issue ################
            newR=self.xorBytes(fOfRK,L)
            ################### end issue ##################
            print('newR: ', self.printListInX(newR, 4))
            #L=newL, R=newR, C=newC, D=newD
            R=newR
            L=newL
            print('L', (i+1), ': ', self.printListInX(L, 4))
            print('R', (i+1), ': ', self.printListInX(R, 4))
        #now that rounds are done, do final permutation (ipTableINV)
        self.encryptedBits=self.finalPermutation(L+R)
        return self.encryptedBits
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.ipTable=[58,50,42,34,26,18,10,2,
            60,52,44,36,28,20,12,4,
            62,54,46,38,30,22,14,6,
            64,56,48,40,32,24,16,8,
            57,49,41,33,25,17,9,1,
            59,51,43,35,27,19,11,3,
            61,53,45,37,29,21,13,5,
            63,55,47,39,31,23,15,7]
        self.ipTableINV=[40,8,48,16,56,24,64,32,
            39,7,47,15,55,23,63,31,
            38,6,46,14,54,22,26,30,
            37,5,45,13,53,21,61,29,
            36,4,44,12,52,20,60,28,
            35,3,43,11,51,19,59,27,
            34,2,42,10,50,18,58,26,
            33,1,41,9,49,17,57,25]
```

this is the driver program use to run and create outputs:

```
from DES64Bit import DES 

cipher=DES()

pt="0123456789ABCDEF"

key="0123456789ABCDEF"

cipher.encrypt(pt=pt, key=key, numRounds=2)
```

the output generated from this is as follows
[DES_OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE0An.png)

the isse here is in the third from last round before start of round two "newR:  "
this line should consist of the previous two lines exclusive or'd.

i have here a program using the same method used internally as well as the same bit string

```
def xorBytes(n, m):
    #assume n m of equal size
    temp=[]
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] == m[i]:
            temp.append(0)
        else:
            temp.append(1)
    return temp

n=[1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0, 1,0,1,0, 1,0,1,0, 1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0, 1,0,1,0, 1,0,1,0]

m=[0,0,1,1, 1,0,0,0, 1,1,0,1, 1,0,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,0,0,1, 1,1,0,0, 1,0,1,1]

print(xorBytes(n,m))
```

(apologies i couldnt get the last 3 lines to get included in the code sample)

the output from this program is as follows:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

this is what should be outputted along with "newR: "

this error occurs on every round at this point, when i XOR L(i-1) with F(E(R(i-1) XOR K(i)))

I dont know exactly whats causing this error but the variable i use to store this result isn't used at all before its creation there. The XOR method i use is used previously and after, it's only at this location in each round that it's incorrect. Every time, at this point, the result ends up being a correctly sized list of all 1's.  the two lists inputed into my XOR method are outputted previously so they exist and contain the correct elements.

I would appreciate any help with this. As mentioned at the start, this is likely more of a python issue than DES issue.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a more minimal example? This is *some* code to read..

Comment: in the image provided, the last 3 lines are "L0:  ...", "F1: ...", and "newR: ...".
newR sould be L0 XOR F1. the last code example given is my XOR function as well as an example of those two going through it. when isolated, there is no issue. Its only each round at the final XOR call that theres an issue

Comment: in the large code sample, the second to last method is my encrypt method. that's where everything happens. the line this issue exists on is surrounded by comments saying "issue start" "issue end"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing types... sometimes you use list of characters `'0'` and `'1'` and sometime list of numbers `0` and `1`.

In Python `0 == '0'` will return `False` and thus the X-Or will be all ones.

Just convert everything to use characters or everything to use numbers, don't mix them.

For other comparison types (e.g. `<`) Python 3 would have given an error, but for equality test different types just compare different no matter what the value is.